# Why is video.srcObject not working with WebRTC?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, networking, socket.io, webrtc

Here's my simple code

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import io from "socket.io-client";

import Navbar from "../../components/Navbar";

export default function ViewerRoom() {
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);
  const localVid = useRef();
  const remoteVid = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const init = async () => {
      //Get URL Params
      const searchParams = new URL(window.location).searchParams;
      const proxy = searchParams.get("v");

      //Define Streams
      const localStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video: true,
        audio: true,
      });
      let remoteStream = new MediaStream();

      //Create RTCPeerConnection
      const servers = {
        iceServers: [
          {
            urls: [
              "stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302",
              "stun:stun1.2.google.com:19302",
            ],
          },
        ],
        iceCandidatePoolSize: 10,
      };
      let pc = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);

      //Add the tracks
      localStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
        pc.addTrack(track, localStream);
      });

      //Pull the tracks from the remote stream
      pc.ontrack = (event) => {
        event.streams[0].getTracks().forEach((track) => {
          remoteStream.addTrack(track);
        });
      };

      //Initialize Socket
      const newSocket = io("http://localhost:1829");
      setSocket(newSocket);

      //Create Data object
      const data = {
        id: proxy,
      };

      //Join Call
      newSocket.emit("join", JSON.stringify(data));

      //Joined Call Auth Callback
      newSocket.on("join-call", (buffer) => {
        //Deserialize
        const data = JSON.parse(buffer);

        //Get that SDP
        const answer = data.offer;
        const remoteDescription = new RTCSessionDescription(answer);
        pc.setRemoteDescription(remoteDescription);

        //Get the Ice Candidates and loop over and add them
        data.iceCandidates.map((ice) => {
          const candidate = new RTCIceCandidate(ice);
          pc.addIceCandidate(candidate);
        });
      });

      localVid.current.srcObject = localStream;
      remoteVid.current.srcObject = remoteStream;
    };
    init();
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <div>
        <>
          <video
            ref={localVid}
            muted
            id="local"
            autoPlay
            width={600}
            height={480}
          />
          <video
            ref={remoteVid}
            id="remote"
            autoPlay
            width={600}
            height={480}
            style={{ marginLeft: "150px" }}
          />
        </>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Everything works. The socket connects, `peer.ontrack` gets fired, the stream gets updated, everything. But the video doesn't display in the UI. The local video gets displayed, but not the remote one. What's wrong? Is it a bug in the browser API? Is it something in my code? I've been scratching my head for hours but I can't get a solution for this problem
If it helps, I'm using React and Es6. Please give a solution

Answer (score 1):

I think the remote video element doesn't play because `autoplay` doesn't work unless the element is also `muted`. But calling `play()` programmatically should work.

```
// ...
localVid.current.srcObject = localStream;
remoteVid.current.srcObject = remoteStream;
remoteVid.current.play();
```

Comment: nope, still not working @chrisguttandin

Comment: Is this a WebRTC error? Or some React bug?

Comment: It's hard to tell. It could be everything or a weird interaction. ;-) A few things that might be worth checking... Does it work/not work in a particular browser? Is `pc.ontrack` actually called? Does it work if you call `play()` after you populated the stream with the remote tracks?

Comment: `pc.ontrack` does get called, I have verified it by console.logging the event itself.  I tried calling `play()` in the ontrack callback, but nothing happened. Is it just some weird bug?

Comment: Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I have no idea. Does it fail in all browsers or is this only happening in a certain browser? Maybe it helps if you only assign the remoteStream to the `srcObject` property when it contains all the tracks. Or you try accessing the tracks from the track event like this: `pc.ontrack = (event) => remoteStream.addTrack(event.track)`. ... These are just ideas. I have no idea if any of this actually works. :-(

Comment: Just FYI: I have the same problem with vanilla JS implementation